# asyncio thread-like behaviour

Tags: python-asyncio

I need to execute an async function in a non blocking way.
Here is my code simplified:

```
import asyncio
async def f():
    print("started")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("bye")
    
async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    loop.create_task(f())
    print("hi")

asyncio.run(main())
```

The code prints:

```
hi
started
```

But the f function never ends..
Basically I just need to return ok message to an http request, and start calculation in the background, in a non blocking way (like a thread), but without using a thread, just await this coroutine. And the main function should return and not await.
Thanks

Comment: `f()` is started in the background but due to the  `main` function is finished the program is terminated. You can see that by adding `await asyncio.sleep(2)` at the end of `main`.

Comment: Then how can I get f to finish? (I need main to return an answer to the client before f finished and it should finish to do that..) @alex_noname

Comment: In the case above, `f()` will finish itself because it will reach the end.

Comment: You can await the task returned by `create_task`.

Comment: @dirn Thanks for your comment, I can't await from the main function, because f should keep running after main has finished.